# How to conditionally render a Login OR a Dashboard based on a user Redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

This is my code:

```
// Components 
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'; 
import Login from './Authentication/Login'; 
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

// Redux import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'; 
import { selectUser } from '../userSlice';

function Authentication() {

    // Redux to manage user state
    var user = useSelector(selectUser); // Use the userReducer called "user"

    return (
    <>
        {user ? <Dashboard /> : <Login />}
    </>
    )
}

export default Authentication;
```

This is my store and my slice:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'; 
import userReducer from './userSlice';

export default configureStore({ 
    reducer: { 
        user: userReducer, 
    }, 
});
```

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = { user: null, };

export const userSlice = createSlice({ 
    name: "user", 
    initialState, 
    reducers: { 
        login: (state, action) => { state.user = action.payload; }, 
        logout: (state) => { state.user = null; } }, 
    }
);

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user; 
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it. I wanted to make sure that if user state is null, then we go to login, else we go to the dashbord.

This is my login code:

```
// Imports
import react from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

// Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { login, selectUser } from '../../userSlice';


// Styling
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

// Google O-Auth
import { GoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login';
import Signup from './Signup';
const clientID = "743792005372-l001hnasupsvimqur3hq32pe8ngje3rr.apps.googleusercontent.com"

function Login() {

    // Step 1: Add O-Auth functionality 
    // Step 2: Add onClick functionality after submission 
    // Step 3: Add useNavigate hook from React Router to redirect to user-specific Dashboard


    // Redux to manage user state
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user); // Use the userReducer called "user"
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); // Use the dispatch function to update the userReducer

    // const [ user, setUser ] = useState({});
    const navigate = useNavigate();


    function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
        var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
        console.log("User logged in successfully!");
        console.log(userObject);

        // Use Redux to set state of user
        dispatch(login(userObject)); // Here, login is the action and userObject is the action.payload 

        navigate('/dashboard');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        /*global google*/
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: clientID,
            callback: handleCallbackResponse
        });

        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById('signInButton'),
            { theme: 'outline', size: 'large', type: 'standard' }
       );

    }, []);



    return (
        <Container align="center" sx={{ mt: '2rem' }}>
            <Typography variant="h3">Welcome to</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h1">ReadHub</Typography>


            <Box id="signInButton" sx={{ m: 4 }}>
                {/* <GoogleLogin
                    clientId={clientID}
                    buttonText={"Login"}
                    onSuccess={onSuccess}
                    onFailure={onFailure}
                    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                    isSignedIn={true}
                /> */}
            </Box>


        </Container>
    );
}
export default Login;
```

Now, there the problem is: On reloading, and going to the root route ("/"), which is where Authentication component is being rendered, the desired behavior is- if logged in then go redirect to dashboard. However, I simply get a white screen with vague errors "Error in Login component".

Comment: I'm afraid the "vague error" is exactly what we'd need to hear more about...

Comment: The app needs to be in loading/authenticating state, I had [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584933/2122822) a similar question, hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have to add a status property, in this there will be three possible states, `'checking'`, `'authenticated'` or `'not-authenticated'`, you can add it in your userSlice, the initial state of this will be `'checking'` , when you finish the authentication verification of your user, place it `'authenticated'` or `'not-authenticated'` depending on the result of this.

If you don't wait for the user to finish loading, the login screen will be rendered first and what is happening to you will happen. To correct it, you just have to do the following in your component:

```
function Authentication() {

    // Redux to manage user state
    var user = useSelector( selectUser ); // Use the userReducer called "user"

    var status = useSelector( selectStatus );
    // status = 'not-authenticated'; // 'authenticated'; // 'not-authenticated';

    if ( status === 'checking' ) {
        return (
            <Loading />
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                status === 'authenticated'
                    ? <Dashboard />
                    : <Login />
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

All the best. I hope it helps you.

Comment: But if I start with a "loading/checking" status, won't I be stuck in that loop forever? Since I'm handling the actual authentication part in the <Login /> component

Comment: Ok, I think I've figured out what the issue is. Whenever I'm refreshing the page, I'm losing state. Even if I manually go to localhost:5000, the state gets refreshed