# how would you fetch data and use it across whole app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch

Hi iam new to react and been thinking about this for a while,
I want to make react application ,

how would you continue?

- I want to fetch data and use it all across the app( best would be just one time when user logs in)

I was thinking about fetching it with redux, but there may be much better way which iam missing.

Thx all

Comment: Redux,  Saga and  MobX - https://npmtrends.com/flux-vs-mobx-vs-redux-vs-redux-saga

Comment: React context should do that,  using AuthContext that keep logged in user info, I had [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584933/2122822) a related question

Answer (score 3):

If it is just one simple api request, then you are better of with using Context API. Just call the API with any network library such as fetch or axios, and keep data inside the Context. And use that Context in the whole App.

As the application's complexity grows and you need more functionality you can then use more sophisticated libraries such as Redux for managing state(keeping data at client app), calls to API will still be done with fetch or axios.

Answer (score 1):

if you have small app better way you used contextApi and other wise you need to used redux is best way for state management

for redux you need to prefer below link
https://enappd.com/blog/redux-in-react-native-app/92/

for context APi :
https://blog.devgenius.io/react-native-state-management-with-context-api-61f63f5b099

Answer (score 1):

- Redux if your app is a SPA (single page application) since redux loses all state on page refresh
- Persistent storage like `localStorage` or cookies until they expire. This method will survive page refreshes.
- Store it in a database on the backend which will keep it until you literally delete it, but I imagine your use-case isn't in need of such a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

State management like redux is the best way to achieve your goal.