# react external redirect and maintaining of state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I have an ecommerce app in which users can login, add products to a cart, then proceed to checkout with Stripe Checkout. I've made two pages for Checkout session success/cancel. However, these two pages are protected, and only an authenticated user can view them. I also have a useEffect in my main App.js component that gets current user info out of local storage. The problem is that the useEffect in App.js isn't firing on re-direct to the success and cancel pages, so users are being re-directed to a login page after returning from the external Checkout session. So, how do I tell my app to look for a currentUser in local storage  immediately after a Stripe Checkout session succeeds or is canceled, but before the App loads?

relevant code in app.js:

```
const [checkoutIncrement, setCheckoutIncrement] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    let checkUserData = () => {
      let userData = localStorage.getItem('store-user')
      if (userData){
        let userData2 = JSON.parse(userData)
        let existingToken = userData2.token
        var decoded = jwt_decode(existingToken);
        let expTime = decoded.exp
        let currentTime = (new Date().getTime() + 1) / 1000
 
        if (expTime > currentTime){
          setCurrentUserEmail(userData2.email)
          setCurrentUser(userData2.username)
          setCurrentToken(userData2.token)
          setCurrentUserId(userData2._id)
        } else {
          localStorage.clear()
        }
      }
    }
    checkUserData()
  }, [checkoutIncrement]);
```

cart.js:

```
  const handleCheckout = async () => {

    let baseURL = 'http://localhost:4000'
    let queryUrl = baseURL + "/api/checkout/combo/handle-get-details-then-checkout"

    let reqBody = { items: []}
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.cartItems.length; i++){
      let currentCartItem = cart.cartItems[i]
      let newObj = {}
      newObj['id'] = currentCartItem.product
      newObj['quantity'] = currentCartItem.quantity
      reqBody['items'].push(newObj)
    }

    let checkoutData = await axios.post(queryUrl, reqBody, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}` },
    });
    if (checkoutData.data.url){
      setCheckoutIncrement(checkoutIncrement ++)
      window.location.href = checkoutData.data.url
    }
  }
```

I thought that changing checkoutIncrement state as I initiated a Stripe Checkout session would cause App.js to re-render after the Checkout session, but it did not re-render. So, on re-direct after the session, the app doesn't know about the existing user anymore. Ideas?

Comment: I think youll need to set the app in loading state, till the info from local storage is loaded

Comment: I tried     setIsLoading(true)
    checkUserData()
    setIsLoading(false) but that did not fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried adding console.log statements to debug? That way you can trace the flow of what's happening here and exactly which pieces of code are being called and when.

Comment: Yes my original code has tons of console.logs, I just removed them to keep the code I post here clean. I don't think flush is the right option, as it would clear other state that I need to keep track of

Comment: Do you think this could be related to [redirect to login on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74584784/2122822)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. If I check for a user in local storage with useMemo, this runs BEFORE render, which is what I wanted. UseEffect wasn't working because it ran AFTER render.