# useContext auth hook returning null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have created a `useAuth` hook in order to allow the user access to the private route once authorised the authorising cookie is stored properly but the `useAuth` hook seems to be returning null. I also tried printing the value of `setUser` but it doesn't seem to print after the line `setUser(res.data.currentUser)` but the one before is printed I cannot figure out why.

The cookies are stored and set properly it just seems to be the auth hook that return `setUser` as null even though the line `console.log("RES>DATA = ", res.data.currentUser);` logs the correct details of the cookie but when I try to manually change the url to the private route after the cookie is stored it returns a null for the `setUser` returned from the auth hook and so access to private route isn't granted. This is done using react for frontend with node js and express for the backend. If any more context is necessary please let me know.

useAuth hook:

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import axios from "axios";

export default function useAuth() {
  const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("USE effect");
    setUserContext();
  });

  //set user in context and push them home
  const setUserContext = async () => {
    console.log("In here");
    return await axios
      .get("auth/checkAuth")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("RES>DATA = ", res.data.currentUser); // PRINTS THE CORRECT COOKIE VALUES
        setUser(res.data.currentUser); // THIS SEEMS TO BE NULL?????
        console.log("SET USER + ", setUser);  // THIS DOES NOT PRINT
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });
  };

  return {
    setUser,
  };
}
```

Private route:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContext } from '../hooks/UserContext';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';


export default function PrivateRoute({children}) {
   const auth = useAuth();
   console.log("aUTH in priv = ", auth);
   return auth ? children : <Navigate to="/"/>
}
```

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import { Redirect, Route, Routes, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Activities from "./components/Activities";
import HomePage from "./components/Home";
import Map from "./components/Map";

import checkUser from "./hooks/checkUser";

import { UserContext } from "./hooks/UserContext";
import useFindUser from "./hooks/checkUser";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";

function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
  const notInitialRender = useRef(false);
  const { user, setUser, isLoading } = useFindUser(); // works as expected



  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser, isLoading }}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}></Route>
          <Route path="/Activities" element={<Activities />} />
          <Route
            path="/Private"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <Map />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

auth/checkAuth express route:

```
export const checkAuth = (req, res) => {

  let currentUser;
  console.log("res.cookies = ", req);
  if (req.cookies.currentUser) {
    // res.send(200);
    currentUser = req.cookies.currentUser; // set to user object in cookies
    console.log("current user = ", currentUser);
    // return 200 status code
  } else {
    currentUser = null;
  }
  //res.json(currentUser);
  res.status(200).send({ currentUser });
};
```

Map component which is private route component:

```
import react from 'react';



function Map() {
    <div>
        <p style={{color:'red'}}>You have access to the private route</p>
    </div>
}

export default Map;
```

UserContext file:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext("null");
```

I tried logging values and using useEffect to call the function when the useAuth hook is called but couldn't figure it out

Comment: Could you share your `UserContext` file too

Comment: React [batches updates](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates) so the console will not return the updated values,  but going throught a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584933/2122822) could help you understand the issue better and fix it

Comment: @RyanZeelie yes just updated the question with UserContext

Comment: inside useAuth hook first line should be destructure user also :
``const {user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);``
and not return {setUser} from hook. only neet to return user like this ``return user``
if your other code and concept work fine then i think after implementing this solution everything will be fine

Comment: @AshrafulMijan it still seems to return null do I need to add a loading part perhaps?

Comment: my useEffect inside useAuth seems to run infinitely?

Comment: @taat may be you can remove "null" from there you createContext it should be empty

Comment: @AshrafulMijan yeah the useEffect seems to run infinitely inside useAuth which keeps calling the setUserContext() function

Comment: @taat actually It's not good things to run useEffect infinitly but i did not notice there is any needy dependancy

Comment: @AshrafulMijan ok it seems to return the child component being my Map component which is listed above and is the child inside the private route in app js but the div paragraph text is not displaying

Comment: @AshrafulMijan yeah i realised I added dependency but I have the issue stated in previous comment now

Comment: Once again to varifay that the children element render properly or not. Just replace with a basic div with some text if the div display properly or not know us i will reply again.