# How to handle auth user in axios interceptor?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I am handling auth user by catching all responses in axios interceptor, I am checking status code of each response and would be navigate to login page if `Unauthorized 401`, but I have a conflict problem when handling login request at login page, if I receive the response status code 401 (eg: username or password incorrect) that will be navigate to login page again. How can I ignore navigate to the login page if this response status code is received at the login page?

My code below:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response.data;
    },
    (error) => {
        if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
            return Router.push('/login');   // it should be won't navigate to login page if this response status code received from login page. How can I solve this?
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);
```

Please help me!

Comment: It will be better to handle it inside a http context, by putting a wrapper around axios, and handling the setting of auth  when you get an unauthorized response

Comment: @Azzy  can you give me an example ?

Comment: If you [handle auth this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584933/2122822), its a matter of just setting the auth user/flag to falsy

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using different Axios instances for specific purposes.

For example, create one for general API usage with your interceptors and another for special cases like logging in where you don't want any interference.

```js
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com",
});
apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  null,
  (err) => {
    if (err.response?.status === 401) {
      return Router.push('/login');
    }
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);

const authClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com/login",
});
```

---

Alternately, you can create conditional interceptors...

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  null,
  (err) => {
    if (err.response?.status === 401) {
      return Router.push("/login");
    }
    return Promise.reject(err);
  },
  {
    runWhen: (config) => config.url !== "/login",
  }
);
```

Comment: `runWhen` not work in axios response interceptor

Comment: I fixed it issue with:  `(error?.response?.status === 401 && error.response.config.url !== '/login')`